# Tikz - Curved Wavy Arrow

Tags: tikz-arrows, arrows, decorations

I would like to create a curved wavy arrow with Tikz. Using the solution from here ([How to get a wavy arrow for an edge?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347736/how-to-get-a-wavy-arrow-for-an-edge)), I can create straight wavy arrows, but adapting to curves does not work and produces artifacts.

MWE:

```
    \documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
    
    %%%
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
    \usepackage[compat=1.0.0]{tikz-feynman}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,angles,quotes,decorations.pathmorphing}
    \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
    
    \begin{document}
        \tikzset{decorate sep/.style 2 args=
            {decorate,decoration={shape backgrounds,shape=circle,shape size=#1,shape sep=#2}}}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[<->,    > = stealth',
            shorten > = 1pt,auto,
            node distance = 3cm,
            decoration = {snake,   % <-- added
                pre length=3pt,post length=1pt,% <-- for better looking of arrow,
            },
            ]
            
            %\path[draw=cyan,decorate] (5.0,0.2) edge [bend left=60] (2.2,0.2) node [above] {}; % curved line removes waves and has artifacts
            \path[draw=cyan, decorate] (5.0,0.2) -- (2.2,0.2) node [above] {}; % straight wavy line
        \end{tikzpicture}  
    \end{document}
```

The MWE produces this:

[image]

The commented line produces this:

[image]

Any hints or alternative methods appreciated!

Comment: Just replace `edge` with `to`.

Comment: Either replace `edge` by `to` as suggested by Sandy or use a different more controllable curve like parabola :
`\path[draw=cyan,decorate] (5.0,0.2) to [bend left=60] (2.2,0.2);`
`\draw[draw=cyan, decorate] (5.0,0.2) parabola[bend pos=0.5] bend +(0,0.2)  (2.2,0.2);`